# Help identifying movie where a virus sent from the future is encoded with a message

Tags: story-identification, movie, time-travel, virus, the-andromeda-strain

I have been struggling with trying to come up with this movie name for a while now, but being in the middle of a pandemic has made it next to impossible to google for "virus" related things that are non-covid.

**Things my memory is pretty solid on:**

- The main plot follows a group of researchers trying to discover the cure to a virus/disease that had not been seen or studied before.
- while trying to identify something related to the virus (either the virus itself or a container related to it? this I am fuzzy on) they discover that it is strangely patterned or geometric.
- One of the researchers is able to decode the virus to reveal a message from the future

**Things I think are correct but might be wrong on**

- The message in the virus is how to cure it, or a similar virus. People in the future sent the virus back in time so that a cure could be developed before it spread to far. It is possible that the virus nearly wiped out humans in the other timeline.
- There may have been space travel/space stations involved, I seem to remember some sort of suits with self contained air supplies. I am unsure if it was space related or just your normal bio-hazard suit.
- The virus may have come from space, or from some sort of container.
- For whatever reason I think of the word Andromeda being related to this movie, but maybe it was just a callback to the Crichton book/movie since aside from the researchers and virus the other points don't line up.

**Additional information**

- I saw the movie on North American television sometime between 2005-2010.
- From what I can remember of style, it was probably a medium to large budget Hollywood movie probably shot sometime between late 80s to early 2000s
- Movie was in English, I believe it mostly took part in the states but this might be wrong.

And just to narrow things down a bit further from my own (fruitless) searching, the movie I am thinking of is not 12 Monkeys, The Andromeda Strain (1971 movie), Contagion.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Could this be the two-part ***[The Andromeda Strain](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0424600/)*** mini-series from 2008...?

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Andromeda_Strain_(miniseries)):

> *The Andromeda Strain* is a 2008 science fiction miniseries, based on the 1969 novel of the same name written by Michael Crichton about a team of scientists who investigate a deadly disease of extraterrestrial origin. The miniseries is a "reimagining" of the original novel rather than an adaptation. In addition to updating the setting to the early 21st century, the miniseries makes a great many plot and character changes from its source. The mini-series has two episodes for a total of 169 minutes.

> A United States government satellite crash lands near Piedmont, Utah, and two teenagers find it and bring it back to town. The town's inhabitants open it and release a deadly microorganism, which is later codenamed Andromeda by the U.S. Army.
>
> [...]
>
> As Andromeda grows and mutates into more virulent forms and takes host in anything from mammals and reptiles to the bird population, the Wildfire team continue their tests to find a way to stop Andromeda before it reaches Las Vegas, the closest city to the quarantine zone with an international airport. Further studies reveal Andromeda is actually a sulfur-based bacterium. A set of tests with bacteriophages reveals that one phage can kill Andromeda. However, repeated tests with this phage prove unsuccessful, causing the Wildfire team to theorize that Andromeda can communicate through an unknown mechanism among its separate parts. **By the time they discover a binary code on Andromeda's cell wall encoded on buckyballs with potassium and rubidium atoms, the team suspects Andromeda to be a message according to the Messenger Theory. The information included the six-digit number "739528" and the words "Bacillus infernus" encoded in ASCII plus a bitmap image of a symbol with interlocking triangles. Bacillus infernus is the name of a bacterium found only in the thermal vents.** At this time, President Scott was championing the new and controversial industry of thermal vent mining, and it was likely that the mining would eradicate the bacteria. Wildfire requests samples of the bacteria to begin testing its effects on Andromeda.
>
> **Tests with Bacillus infernus reveal that the bacterium easily consumes and destroys Andromeda because of Andromeda's sulfur structure. The Wildfire team begins to grow large amounts of the bacterium in culture vats, intending to spray the culture liquid over a quarantine area in an attempt to sanitize it of the extraterrestrial bacterium.**
>
> [...]
>
> **In the final scene, the saved sample of the Andromeda is inserted into a BSL-4 compartment with the access code "739528", held in a vessel marked with a symbol with interlocking triangles.** Director Beeter watches over the operation on the computer in his office. **The camera then zooms out, revealing Andromeda has been stored within a space station orbiting Earth. The ending implies that the sample saved on the space station is the cause of the outbreak in the future that necessitated sending the organism back to the present via the wormhole, creating an ontological paradox as to the cell's origin.**

Comment: Timeline fits, plot points fit, and remembering of Andromeda fits. I was pretty sure it wasn't the tv series as nothing jogged my memory when watching the trailers before posting the question. Will have to figure out which streaming service has the rights where I am and give it a watch. After reading your plot synopsis I think you have it right tho. Will probably give you the check tomorrow after watching it, thanks!

Comment: After a watch through, this was it. I must have seen it during it's original showing on A&E back around 2008. Thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: @Malco If you're looking for more material, there's a 1971 film by the same name, and the original 1969 book by Michael Crichton. The book was written during a fairly eventful period of history in molecular biology (the 60s saw some major breakthroughs in the field, such as the interpretation of genetic codes for protein synthesis) and the writing, while a little dated, captures a lot of that excitement.

Comment: @Polynomial Ya, I watched it the other night thinking it was what I was looking for, was the reason I finally made this question since I thought I must have remembered the movie name wrong. the og one has nothing for the time travel wormhole stuff. having watched both back to back I think the 1971 on is my preference.

Comment: well...being a fan of the novel and original movie, I recall knowing the new adapation existed but never watched. reading the synoposis above...made the right call